# Wubi-like installer for Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, wubi

Is there an application like [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/) for other Linux distributions?

More specifically, I'd love to install Fedora without a dedicated partition or changing my bootloader.

Comment: There is a ongoing port by a Seneca college student <br/> http://lsdaly.blogspot.com/2008/10/wubi-port-project.html <br/>
http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Wubi_port_to_Fedora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so.  Great idea though!

Comment: there was Wubix (an inofficial wubi fork to be used with any Linux distro), but the project seems to be cancelled, or at least the download is no longer available. http://sourceforge.net/projects/wubix/

Comment: There never was a WubiX, it's in the "planning" stage and has been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), it works with different distros. There is what they call a "frugal" mode which installs to a hard drive, but to a separate partition.

> UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu,
>   Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on
>   Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X

[image]