# How to installl Fedora without Cd Rom/DVD drive and booting from USB?

Tags: installation, fedora, boot.ini

Hi is it possible to install Fedora on a computer with a screwed CD/DVD Drive (Doesn't Work) and no USB Boot option on start up?

I tried Unetbootin it doesnt work either I get 
"Invalid Boot File" on reload and it just loads Windows XP which is the current os on the system!

Any other way??

In response to what Ivo just said... basically i have the fedora 12 iso, i run Unetbootin and select the "Hard Disk" option, then unetbootin does its thing and asks me to restart the computer, which i do and according to the unetbootin website i should get something like a Grub Bootloader screen, which i dont and i get this text
"Invalid Boot.ini File"
Booting from C:\Windows
and winxp starts up

I did have a look at the Boot.ini file that unetbootin created and it had one line init..
which i dont remeber properly something like

C:\something.mbr [ i did want to install fedora 12 as my primary and only operating system on the computer]

I changed the boot.ini file's contents to the default winxp boot.ini file before posting this question cause unetbootin was not working.

Comment: If you would be OK with Ubuntu, you could run wubi from within Windows. Since there's no alternative for Fedora: http://superuser.com/questions/87632/wubi-like-installer-for-fedora

Comment: I fear Unetbootin is your only real option, I suggest editing this question to describe your issue with it, so we can help you with it

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes, it *is* possible. It's essentially a remote install of FC.

1. Defrag
2. Repartition to have a small partition in which you unpack the .iso
3. Install grub (That's the tricky one. you'll have to use [grub4dos](https://gna.org/projects/grub4dos/). The [PuppyLinux wiki](http://pupweb.org/wikka/InstallingPuppyOnNTFS) has a good walkthrough, although they do it slightly differently than I suggest)
4. Boot from the new partition
5. install fedora over the XP partition
6. boot into fedora and remove the partition in which you've unpacked the .iso
7. resize the fedora partitions appropriately to recover the lost space.

But it remains easier to grab your disk and get a friend to install it for you on a separate machine.

for more info on remote, headless installs have a look at [the depenguinator](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-01-29-depenguinator-2.0.html) or [The Archlinux wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remote_Arch_Linux_Install). You have the advantage of having access to the screen/kbd and so don't need to set up ssh.

Comment: my laptop is Acer Aspire5030, amd Turion 64 Win Xp Sp2, my friend has a hp laptop with an intel processor if i put my hd in that one (to install fedora) woud the fact that his is an intel processor be an issue?

Comment: Nah, should be fine, it's all x86. Configuration might be a little more complicated. Make sure to install the drivers for *your* laptop, not your friend's. (especially networking and display). You might have to manually change which drivers are used when you transfer the drive across to you machine. Pop up another question on SU if you run into trouble. (If it's any reassurance, I installed Archlinux from an AMD64X2 and am now using the drive with a VIA Epia.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to another computer and have some sapre time, I would recommend installing it using this other computer. Since Linux usually reconfigures itself well, you could install Linux on your drive by using another computer. Just take the hard disk and install it temporarily on another computer.

Comment: not a bad idea.  make sure to disconnect other hard drives in the temporary computer to avoid problems, and be aware you may need to modify Grub before moving the drive back to it's primary system.

Answer (score 0):

Or bring someone's external DVD-R drive and connect it to USB.. then boot from it.

Or use Fedora through VMWare(Just suggesting, do it if you think it'll serve your purpose)..